# How can I grab and store multiple $_POST Variables in a for each loop?

Tags: php, mysql, post, for-loop, survey

So currently I am using a 3rd party software application to get results from various surveys.  This application is sending the results to a page via a $_POST variable.

So for example..

```
$demoEMP = $_POST['demoEMP'];
```

This just stores the answer from the specific question into a variable.

What I want to do is store Questions 1-20 in POST variables and Insert them into a database..
What I don't want to do is write 20+ Insert commands or 20+  $var = $_POST['var']

So I was thinking a for loop would do the trick... This is what I have so far... based on looking at various methods and tutorials.  =/

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 55; $i++) {
$answer = "Q{$i}";
echo $_POST[$answer];
}
```

### Am I even on the right track?  Thanks for your help!

UPDATE::
Kas' solution worked great.

I used something like this...

```
foreach ($_POST as $i => $v)
{
if (preg_match("/^Q\d+$/",$i)) {

// Here we insert value $v to database
$query_2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO SGresult VALUES ('', '', '$pID', '$SGQID','$v')") or die('Error: '.mysql_error ());
```

}
}

However, I am now trying to figure a way to add an ID to the question and have that ID auto increment... on every insert.  I thought I could do something like $SGQID++ but that does not seem to be working.. anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks again!

okay after some more tinkering it seems the placement of the ++ was off and it needed to be after the query... the correct code is as follows.

```
$SGQID= 1;

foreach ($_POST as $i => $v)
{

if (preg_match("/^Q\d+$/",$i)) {

// Here we insert value $v to database
$query_2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO SGresult VALUES ('', '', '$pID', '$SGQID','$v')") or die('Error: '.mysql_error ());
$SGQID++; //added value to increment Question ID in DB

}
}
```

Comment: yes, you are almost on right track. you can use count($_POST) instead of 55. also foreach could be used with a $counter variable.

Comment: Using a foreach() over the $_POST array and filtering on the key names is a better solution, because using a for loop with count($_POST) assumes you number the $_POST variables consecutively, and that no other variables are passed to your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($_POST as $i => $v) {
  if (preg_match("/^Q\d+$/",$i)) {
    // Here we insert value $v to database
  }
}
```

Comment: Currently giving this a shot Kas, I have never used preg_match before.  Thank you, I will keep you posted!

Comment: Hey Kan, this worked great!  However, I want to throw an auto increment value based on every insert I do, starting with 1.  See the edited question above.

Comment: autoincrement value is set by database at least in case You use sql: CREATE TABLE questions (`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,`text` TEXT NOT NULL) ENGINE = MYISAM;
- For this table insert looks like "insert into questions(`text`) values('lalala')" and then You get your autoincrement index by mysql_insert_id() or "select LAST_INSERT_ID from questions"

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the $_POST array itself:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // Filter on value of $key
    // In this case only keep variables that start with a Q
    if (! substr($key, 0, 1) == 'Q') {
        continue;
    }

    // Do something with value
    echo $_POST[$key];     
}
```

If you want to assign the values to PHP variables with the same name as the key of the $_POST array you can use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$$key = $value
```

The value of $_POST['demoEMP'] will then be assigned to $demoEMP.

Comment: Thanks Jan, I will try this out and let you know.  =)