# How can I update an array value and put it into a mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreach

Okay so a while ago I asked this question

[How can I grab and store multiple $_POST Variables in a for each loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794575/how-can-i-grab-and-store-multiple-post-variables-in-a-for-each-loop)

And the response was perfect, and it worked for inserting the values into the database just fine.  However, I now am revisiting this project and I want to UPDATE only one field in the database, specifically the post test field for that particular user, using the same or similar method.  How would this be possible?

Currently I have something along the lines of this.

```
$SGUID = the Unique User ID
$SGpost = the field i want to update
$SGQID = question ID
```

Obviously, this does not work.. and my code is extremely sloppy as I tried to replace and edit this along the way.  Any ideas?

```
foreach ($_POST as $p => $v)
{

 if (preg_match("/^Q\d+$/",$p)) {   //$_POST variables with Q1, Q2, Q3, etc etc

$query_3 = mysql_query("UPDATE SGresults SET SGpost = '$p', SGpostCheck = 1 WHERE SGUID = '$SGUID' AND SGQID = '$p'") or die('Error: '.mysql_error ());
    $SGQID++;

}
}
}
```

When I echo out $p I get the following
    Q11
Q21
Q31
Q44
Q54
Q63
Q73
Q83
Q93
Q103
Q111
Q122
Q131
Q142
Q153
Q163
Q17

Which is what I want, except without the Q, and just the second value.  So for example if it was 'Q163'  I just want to insert the '3' part into SGpost WHERE the database is 'Q16'.

Thanks again again!  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT::
Looked over my code again and changed some values around...The following DOES work, so I think I will stick with it.  Unless bad code?  Thanks again for your suggestions.

```
$SGQID= 1;

foreach ($_POST as $i => $v)
  {
    if (preg_match("/^Q\d+$/",$i)) {    //$_POST variables with Q1, Q2, Q3, etc etc
// Here we insert value $v to database
    if ($SGtestType == "Post-test") {

    $query_post = mysql_query("UPDATE SGresults SET SGpost = '$v', SGpostcheck ='1' WHERE SGQID = '$SGQID' AND SGUID = '$SGUID'  ") or die('Error 109: '.mysql_error ());
    $SGQID++;           
    // ^^ increments the question value everytime an insert is made
    //last 2 fields is check for existing value.. or if not exists.. 1 if it does.
    }
```

}

}
}

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you trust the post data to not be an xss attack:

```
    foreach ($_POST as $p => $v)
    {

     if (preg_match("/^Q(\d+)$/",$p, $matches)) {   //$_POST variables with Q1, Q2, Q3, etc etc

$id = (int)$matches[1];

    $query_3 = mysql_query("UPDATE SGresults SET SGpost = '$id', SGpostCheck = 1 WHERE SGUID = '$SGUID' AND SGQID = '$id'") or die('Error: '.mysql_error ());
        $SGQID++;

    }
    }
    }
```